# How can I get the MobileFirst Foundation SDK to ignore Push Notifications sent by sources other than MobileFirst?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, ibm-mobilefirst

The MobileFirst Foundation SDK push notification receiver doesn't appear to be able to differentiate between notifications coming from MobileFirst and those from other sources.

We are trying to implement push notification in our app such that it can receive notifications from multiple sources.  But what we've observed is that, while other cloud push providers' SDKs on process push notifications sources from that provider, the MobileFirst SDK processes all push notifications received by the device.  This causes notifications sent from the cloud providers to be displayed twice on the device.

Some additional details:

- This seems true regardless of the 3rd party cloud provider.  We've tried 5 and all ignore MobileFirst notifications, however MobileFirst processes notifications from all of them.
- GCM sender ID is the same for MobileFirst as for the other providers.
- We are building native Android and iOS applications.

Answer (score 1):

MobileFirst does not support this functionality out of the box, however because the other push services don't use the MobileFirst adapter used to send notifications via MobileFirst, the key is to add a property to the notification payload that can tell the device whether or not to show the notification.

So for instance, one solution would be to add a custom property in the adapter with the value "mfp" to the payload like this:

```
notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText,
               badgeDigit, {custom:"mfpush"});
```

Then in MyListener.java in the Android native code, add an "if" statement in the onReceive() function.  This will handle the case when the application is running in the foreground:

```
public void onReceive(String props, String payload) {
  JSONObject jsonObject;
  JSONObject payloadJSON;
  String notification = "";
  String payloadNotif = "";

  try {
    // get payload from MFP adapter: custom property
    payloadJSON = new JSONObject(payload);
    payloadNotif = payloadJSON.getString("custom");

    // if the payload "custom" property is "mfp", show the alert,
    // if not, don't show the alert
    if (payloadNotif.contains("mfp")) {
      jsonObject = new JSONObject(props);
      notification = jsonObject.getString("alert");
    }else{
      return;
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  MainActivity.alertMsg("Notification", notification);
}
```

In the case where the application is running in the background, a new class needs to be created that extends com.worklight.wlclient.push.WLBroadcastReceiver and overrides the receive method.  Create a CustomBroadcastReceiver class that extends WLBroadCastReceiver and overrides the onReceive method to call CustomGCMIntentService

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends WLBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     intent.setClassName(context,
CustomGCMIntentService.class.getName());
        WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, intent);     } }
```

Then in CustomGCMIntentService, extend the MFP GCMIntentService class and override the two notify methods to check of the push came from MFP:

```
package com.sample.eventsourcenotificationsandroid.custom;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class CustomGCMIntentService extends GCMIntentService {
    @Override
public void notify(Context context, String tickerText) {
 super.notify(context, tickerText);
}

@Override
public void notify(Context context, String alert, int badge, String
sound, Intent intent) {
 if(isMobileFirstNotification(intent)) {
  super.notify(context, alert, badge, sound, intent);
}     }

@Override
public void notify(Context context, Message message, Intent intent) {
     if(isMobileFirstNotification(intent)) {
     super.notify(context, message, intent);
}     }

private boolean isMobileFirstNotification(Intent intent) {
 Message message = intent.getParcelableExtra("message");
 JSONObject payload = message.getPayload();
 return payload.optBoolean("mfpush", false);
} }
```

The way you're checking for notifications from MFP is by checking that the mfppush key as a value of true in the notification payload.

```
data: {
 badge: "",
 alert: "YourMessageContent",
 sound: "your sound",
 payload:{
  mfpush: true
} }
```

Lastly, the manifest needs to be updated to use the new class instead of com.worklight.wlclient.push.WLBroadcastReceiver as follows:

```
<service android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.push.GCMIntentService" />

<receiver android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.push.WLBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

<!-- removed intent-filter for com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
-->
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="com.sample.eventsourcenotificationsandroid" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<!-- start custom service and receiver -->
<service android:name="com.sample.eventsourcenotificationsandroid.custom.
CustomGCMIntentService" />

<receiver     android:name="com.sample.eventsourcenotificationsandroid.custom.CustomB    roadcastReceiver"
  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="com.sample.eventsourcenotificationsandroid" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<!-- end custom service and receiver -->
```